# replace Array items with it's positions

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

i want to replace each item in array with it's position . simple example:

```
var items = 'ABCDefgh';
//how to replace items with its position to be
[0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7]
```

i use that but it replace the last item only.

```
for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
var items_positions = items.replace(items[i],'['+items.indexOf(items[i])+']');
alert(items_positions);
}
// it returns ABCDefg[7]
```

and try with RegExp

```
for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    var items_positions = items.replace(new RegExp(items[i],"g"),'['+items.indexOf(items[i])+']');
    alert(items_positions);
    }
    // it returns no thing
```

Comment: Why are you using a regex? Why not just count the length of the string and then create the corresponding number of positions?

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. The positions will just be incrementing numbers for everything.

Comment: The problem in both cases is is that every time through the loop, you're overwriting `items_positions` with the result of a single replacement. You're not combining all the replacements.

Comment: ok thanx for replying and other for downvote , whats workarround !

Comment: Why do you even care about the characters?  If you know the length, just generate the result you want from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a copy of `items` first, and then update that each time through the loop. There's no need to use `indexOf()` to find the position of the element, since it will always be the same as `i`.

```js
var items = 'ABCDefghAfi';
var items_positions = items;
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items_positions = items_positions.replace(new RegExp(items[i], 'g'), '[' + i + ']');
}
alert(items_positions);
```

Comment: I can not believe my eyes

Answer (score 1):

This won't actually need a regex.

```js
var items = 'ABCDefgh';
var items_positions = "";
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  
  items_positions += '[' + i + ']';
}
alert(items_positions)
```